# Set viewstate variable at end of page lifecycle

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax

What am I trying to do is to set a ViewState variable at the end of a page lifecycle: what I have, is completely loaded asp.net page - communicating with AJAX calls with client JavaScript... when the ajax call from the client JavaScript is performed, some C# methods from the server code are executed. During this execution, I want to set a ViewState variable and use it on the next postback, but apparently the ViewState variable is not stored - because the page is completely loaded - all logic is performed at the end of the page lifecycle.

I've tried explicitly calling these methods before and after setting the ViewState variable:

```
       this.TrackViewState();
       if (startAddr != "")
       {
           ViewState["startAddress"] = startAddr;
       }
       this.SaveViewState();
```

But with no success... on the next postback, the `ViewState["startAddress"]` is null.

Any suggestions, if the above described functionality can be achieved?!
Thanks!

Comment: Strongly recommend: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override page's [SaveViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.saveviewstate.aspx) method to see if it called before your code. SaveViewState is the very last point where you can store objects in ViewState that are not part of the control-hierarchy.

```
protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    if (startAddr != "")
    {
        ViewState["startAddress"] = startAddr;
    }
    return base.SaveViewState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but actually the SaveViewState() method is not called after the assignment of startAddr...and the assignment is performed during the execution of the c# methods called from the client javascript (ajax)

Comment: ViewState is not persisted during ajax-callbacks. Use a hiddenfield or session instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call directly SaveViewState method.

Check if EnableViewState is set to true in your page. And check if ViewState is really assigned.

Comment: Yes, after debugging - it is obvious that the viewstate variable is assigned, but not stored - on the next postback it has value null

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know,
U don't need to store variable in the `viewstate`,
if ur value is get from the web page,
as u r using **Ajax** to call back (not sure using `CallBack` or `PageMethod`),
u can get value without store it in `viewstate`.
juz store the value in **JS** variable.

let me know, if any suggestion or confusion?

Hope it works!